# Pyqt - QProcess / readAllStandardOutput() - Encoding?

Tags: python, string, qt, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have the following code to start .bat file and read output of process:

```
def WriteFirmwareButtonEvent(self):

    self.process = QProcess(self)
    self.process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels)
    self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.EventDataForReadFromCMD)
    self.process.start("run.bat")

def EventDataForReadFromCMD(self):
    ...
```

I have tried:

```
...
output = bytearray(self.process.readAllStandardOutput())
output = output.decode(xxx)
print (output)
```

But any encoding giving me error about decoding 4th character
So i have tried pure convert to python string:

```
...
output = str(self.process.readAllStandardOutput())
print (output)
```

Will give me :

> b'Syst\x82m nem\x85\xa7e nal\x82zt uvedenou cestu.\r\n'

```
...
output = QByteArray(self.process.readAllStandardOutput())
test = QTextCodec.codecForLocale()
test = test.toUnicode(output)
```

This has same problem unknown character 4 while encoding

But If i run script manually from CMD output should looks like this:

> Systém nemůže nalézt uvedenou cestu.

is there some special encoding of output from QProcess? and his read methods?

The only thing i can do right now is to define my own encoding loop for every unknown character and i hope there is better solution.

Comment: Did you look at `QString::fromLocal8Bit()` and `QTextCodec::codecForLocale()`?

Comment: PyQt5 has no QString anymore

Comment: I believe `QTextCodec` is still available.

Comment: I have meet same problem unknown character :/ check the updated question upper please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i have found the answer...

```
        ...
        output = bytearray(self.process.readAllStandardOutput())
        output = output.decode(self.GetCMD_Encoding())
        print (output)

    def GetCMD_Encoding(self):

        CMD = QProcess(self)
        CMD.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels)
        CMD.start("C:\Windows\System32\chcp.com")
        CMD.waitForReadyRead()
        output = bytearray(CMD.readAllStandardOutput())
        output = output.decode("ascii")
        output = output[18:]
        return "cp" + output
```

Output:

> Systém nemůže nalézt uvedenou cestu.

Comment: You should try to use `QTextCodec.codecForLocale()` as suggested by Benjamin T in the comments to your question instead of hard-coding the charset, if possible. Not everyone's system is set up to use Codepage 852 on the console.

Comment: I tried it, but i have got the same results as with any other coding. Error at character 4th. You can see updated code in the question where i tried it.

Comment: I see, then it's probably ok in your particular case. Looks like whatever is run in the batch file has hard-coded its charset as well, instead of being locale-sensitive.

Comment: theoretically i can get this charset by `chcp` from another Qprocess and then use proper coding :) Can you try `chcp` in CMD on you computer for example? because the standard output from `chcp` i can decode easily by ascii

Comment: Sure, I get `Active code page: 437` as result. My Windows 10's locale is set to US English. Had I set it to German, the result would have most likely been code page 850.

Comment: Hmm i have tried this: `CMD = QProcess(self)` `CMD.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels)`
  `CMD.start("chcp")`
  `CMD.waitForReadyRead()`
  `output = bytearray(CMD.readAllStandardOutput())`
  `output = output.decode("ascii")`
  `print (output)`  But it does not wait for output :( btw is there any way to format comment with code readable?

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell, everything is correct on your system. It may just be `codecForLocale()` that returns a codec unsuitable for the cmd.exe console. Too bad `fromLocal8Bit()` seems to have gone with `QString`, as that might have performed the correct conversion.

Comment: Ok i finally answer the question you can check it if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Python has a codec called `mbcs` that decodes text according to the current ANSI codepage that should do exactly what you need:

```
output = output.decode('mbcs')
```